# Bootstrap 3 + backbonejs - Toggle nav not opening

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I am using jquery, backbonejs, underscorejs and bootstrap 3 for my project (https://izify.com/). This is my source code https://github.com/datomnurdin/izify-template. I can't open toogle nav when click the button.

This is screenshot for toogle nav.

[image]

My offcanvas.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Is there any problem when integrate with backbonejs?

I take the template from here, http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Demo site: http://staging.revivalx.com/izify-template/

Comment: Did you check the console?

Comment: nothing happen. check this demo site. http://staging.revivalx.com/izify-template/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how abt this..cleaner way

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore','backbone','text!templates/home/homeTemplate.html'], function($, _, Backbone, homeTemplate){

 var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
 el: $("#page"),

 events: {
    'click [data-toggle=offcanvas]' :'toggleClass'
 }, 

 render: function(){
    this.$el.html(homeTemplate);
 },

 toggleClass: function (e) {
this.$('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
 }

});

 return HomeView;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove offcanvas.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

And put this line of code

```
$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
        $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
      });
```

into HomeView.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/home/homeTemplate.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, homeTemplate){

  var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),

    render: function(){
      this.$el.html(homeTemplate);

                  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
                    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
                  });
    }

  });

  return HomeView;

});
```

And it works fine.