# Bootstrap 3 + backbonejs - Toogle nav not opening V2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

Back to my old question [Bootstrap 3 + backbonejs - Toogle nav not opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647146/bootstrap-3-backbonejs-toogle-nav-not-opening) regarding to my problem, now I'm facing the problem where toogle nav not opening when I insert sidebar view code into home view

My home.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone','views/sidebar/SidebarView', 'text!templates/home/homeTemplate.html'], function($, _, Backbone,SidebarView, homeTemplate) {
    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#page"),
        initialize: function() {
            this.$el.off();
        },
        events: {
            'click [data-toggle=offcanvas]': 'toggleClass'
        },
        toggleClass: function(e) {
            console.log("fire");
            this.$('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(homeTemplate);

            var sidebarView = new SidebarView();
            sidebarView.render();
        },
    });
    return HomeView;
});
```

https://github.com/datomnurdin/izify-template/blob/master/js/views/home/HomeView.js

My sidebar.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/sidebar/sidebarTemplate.html'], function($, _, Backbone, sidebarTemplate) {
    var SidebarView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#sidebar"),
        initialize: function() {
            this.$el.off();
        },
        events: {
            'click [data-toggle=offcanvas]': 'toggleClass'
        },
        toggleClass: function(e) {
            console.log("fire");
            this.$('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
        },
        render: function() {
            $("#sidebar").append(sidebarTemplate);
        }
    });
    return SidebarView;
});
```

https://github.com/datomnurdin/izify-template/blob/master/js/views/sidebar/SidebarView.js

My repo: [https://github.com/datomnurdin/izify-template/blob/master/js/views/sidebar/SidebarView.js](https://github.com/datomnurdin/izify-template)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If such toggling nav is the functionality that native in Bootstrap, I don't think it's necessary to manage it in Backbone.

There will always be something global, something general. And the better approach is still to used plain old jQuery to manage them, no need to specific to each Backbone view.

My suggestion is, if that's Bootstrap's feature, leave it alone in Backbone, let the event propaganda, and let Bootstrap to manage it.